# funds for gas * price + value. ETH WHALES HELP PLEASE!

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, blockchain, hardhat

I am training on smart contracts and I need Rinkeby eth, I have tried for 3 days unsuccessfully using the rinkeby crypto faucet, following their instructions with a twitter post, but it always gives me the same answer: insufficient funds for gas * price + value, can someone send me some? my address is 0xC69F78646a9dE60dfC7D75d98FF4FbB2912e1Cb6

Answer (score 0):

You can try these faucets and request some Finney (decimal of ETH):

- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby
- https://rinkeby-faucet.com

Answer (score 0):

Most of your training should take place on a simulated blockchain (ganache).

If you absolutely must deploy on an EVM, try other test networks from other chains (like Mumbai). It should work as long as it can be accessed with metamask.